# How to mass add squid users (htpasswd)

Tags: md5, squid, .htpasswd

I normally add a new user in squid with this command

```
touch /etc/squid/squid_access; htpasswd /etc/squid/squid_access "NEWuser"
```

then it prompts me to input the password for "newuser" and conirm it again.

How can I automate this so that I add a range of new users(user1-user500) with the same or password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get what you want with the `seq` command, on which youu can perform a loop in bash. You might get what you want with this or something similar:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /etc/squid/squid_access
for i in $(seq 1 500)
do
    htpasswd /etc/squid/squid_access "new-user-$i"
done
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.